# \scalebox clash with cleveref for custom equation tags

Tags: graphics, cleveref, hieroglf

I wish to tag an equation with a rescaled hieroglyph (most custom symbols from `hieroglf` are way too tall for my liking). However, when I compile

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{amsmath,graphicx,hieroglf,cleveref}

\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}\label{eq:Einstein}
        E=mc^2\tag{\scalebox{0.6}{\textpmhg{\Ha}\!}}
    \end{equation}
    As we see from \cref{eq:Einstein}, 
\end{document}
```

I get the following bad error messages:

> Use of \label@optarg doesn't match its definition. \end{equation}
>
> Argument of \Gscale@box has an extra }. \end{equation}
>
> Paragraph ended before \Gscale@box was complete. \end{equation}

etc. This confuses me greatly, because I do not see an immediate fix of this... protecting the tag with a group `{}` does not work. Can you help me?

Comment: Which TeX distribution do you employ? I ask because I don't experience any problems when I compile your code -- nice MWE, by the way! -- on my machine (MacBook Air M2, MacOS 14.1.2 "Sonoma", and MacTeX2023 with all updates installed).

Comment: It is an older distribution, probably MacTeX2017... how may I check the exact year?

Comment: Check the first line in the log file. Mine says: `This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 (TeX Live 2023) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2023.11.25)  2 DEC 2023 18:38`. Note the substring "TeX Live 2023". MacTeX *is* TeXLive, with the added bonus of some visual utilities.

Comment: For me, it reads: `This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2018) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2018.8.2)  2 DEC 2023 19:16`. (I should specify that I am not able to update my distribution as of now, because it would probably destroy some important documents that I need to be correctly compiled very shortly. I will think about switching to MacTeX during the holidays...)

Comment: there is no error in an up to date texlive 2023, but possbly in older releases use `\tag{\foo}`   with `\DeclareRobustCommand\foo{\scalebox{0.6}{\textpmhg{\Ha}\!}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the command robust and scale using `\fontsize`.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,graphicx,hieroglf,cleveref}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\hiersize}{\fontsize{\fpeval{0.6*\f@size}}{0}\selectfont}
\makeatletter

\NewDocumentCommand{\hier}{m}{\textpmhg{\hiersize#1\!}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{eq:Einstein}
E=mc^2\tag{\hier{\Ha}}
\end{equation}
As we see from \cref{eq:Einstein},

\end{document}
```

[image]

Will your readers know how to read that symbol?

If you only plan to use hieroglyphs at that size, it makes sense to load the fonts already scaled down.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hieroglf}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\DeclareFontFamily{OT1}{pmhg}{}
\DeclareFontShape{OT1}{pmhg}{m}{n}{ <-> s*[0.6] pmhg }{}
\DeclareFontFamily{T1}{pmhg}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{pmhg}{m}{n}{ <-> s*[0.6] pmhg }{}

\NewDocumentCommand{\hier}{m}{\textpmhg{#1\!}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{eq:Einstein}
E=mc^2\tag{\hier{\Ha}}
\end{equation}
As we see from \cref{eq:Einstein},

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 for "Will your readers know how to read that symbol?" :-)

Comment: @Mico Amazingly, yes! :)